# Cron, execute bash script as root, but one part (Python script) as user

Tags: python, bash, cron, cron-task

I need to run a bash script periodically on a Jetson Nano (so, Ubuntu 18.04). The script should run system updates, pull some Python code from a repository, and run it as a specified user.
So, I created this script:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

## system updates
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

## stop previous instances of the Python code
pkill python3

## move to python script folder
cd /home/user_name/projects/my_folder

## pull updates from repo
git stash
git pull

## create dummy folder to check bash script execution to this point
sudo -u user_name mkdir /home/user_name/projects/dummy_folder_00

## launch python script
sudo -u user_name /usr/bin/python3 python_script.py --arg01 --arg02

## create dummy folder to check bash script execution to this point
sudo -u user_name mkdir /home/user_name/projects/dummy_folder_01
```

I created a cron job running this script as root, by using

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and adding the entry

```
00 13 * * * /home/user_name/projects/my_folder/script.sh
```

Now, I can see that at the configured time, both the dummy folders are created, and they actually belong to user_name. However, the Python script isn't launched.

I tried creating the cron job as non root user (crontab -e), but at this point even if the Python script gets exectured, I guess I wouldn't be able to run apt update/upgrade.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if the dummy folders did get created, that means the sudo statements work, so i'd say theres a 99%+ chance that python was infact started.

I'm guessing the problem is that you havent specified the path for the python file, and your working directory likely isn't what you're expecting it to be.

change:

```
sudo -u user_name /usr/bin/python3 python_script.py --arg01 --arg02
```

to something like

```
sudo -u user_name /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/your/python_script.py --arg01 --arg02
```

then test.

If that didn't solve the problem , then enable some logging, change the line to:

```
sudo -u user_name /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/your/python_script.py --arg01 --arg02 \
1> /home/user_name/projects/dummy_folder_00/log.txt 2>&1 ;
```

and test again, it should log STDOUT and STDERR to that file then.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm changing the working directory (cd /home/user_name/projects/my_folder) from the bash script before running the python code, so I guess that shouldn't be the issue. Also, as I said I tried creating the cron job as non root user, and everything works fine.

Comment: yea but running it as `userX` isnt entirely the same as root running `sudo -u userX`, there are some subtle differences (which may or may not matter); i'd check on what the logfiles say.

Comment: Yes, it seems this was the problem, running the Python script like this created some problems in the Python packages that were imported. I'll run this script as non root, and I'll keep the system updates in another cron job, thanks!